# Populate dijit menubar with data from sql database

Tags: c#, jquery, database, json, dojo

I haven't worked so much with jquery, ajax and json before, but I want to learn how to use it using dojo and dijit. There are many tutorials, but few c# with sql database examples.

I've created a json output with dijit menubar data from my database which looks like this:

```
[{"MenuItemId":1,"MenuName":"Root","Tooltip":"Root","IsParent":true,"ParentId":0,"IsVisible":false,"SortIndex":null},
{"MenuItemId":3,"MenuName":"Blogg","Tooltip":"Min Blogg","IsParent":false,"ParentId":1,"IsVisible":true,"SortIndex":1000},
{"MenuItemId":4,"MenuName":"Administrasjon","Tooltip":"Viser Administrasjon","IsParent":true,"ParentId":1,"IsVisible":true,"SortIndex":10000},
{"MenuItemId":5,"MenuName":"DropMenu","Tooltip":"Drop menu","IsParent":true,"ParentId":1,"IsVisible":true,"SortIndex":9000},
{"MenuItemId":6,"MenuName":"Menuitem1","Tooltip":"Menuitem1","IsParent":false,"ParentId":5,"IsVisible":true,"SortIndex":9001},
{"MenuItemId":9,"MenuName":"Menuitem2","Tooltip":"Menuitem2","IsParent":false,"ParentId":5,"IsVisible":true,"SortIndex":9002}]
```

I want to bind these data to dijit menubar, but I haven't figured out how to doo it yet.
Here is the code I've made so far. I've been trying back and forth, but I haven't managed to get data out from the json data I try to get.

Here is a sample in where I try to get data out of my json data output. The sample is trying to write data in console view, but I want to populate a dijit manybar:

```
<script>
    require([
        "dijit/MenuBar",
        "dijit/PopupMenuBarItem",
        "dijit/Menu",
        "dijit/MenuItem",
        "dijit/DropDownMenu",
        "dojo/dom",
        "dojo/request",
        "dojo/json",
        "dojo/_base/array",
        "dojo/domReady!"                
    ], function(MenuBar, PopupMenuBarItem, Menu, MenuItem, DropDownMenu, dom, request, JSON, arrayUtil) {
        console.log('hello world');

        // Results will be displayed in resultDiv
        var resultDiv = dom.byId("resultDiv");

        // Request the JSON data from the server
        request.get("/api/Menu", {
            // Parse data from JSON to a JavaScript object
            handleAs: "json"
        }).then(function(data) {
            // Display the data sent from the server
            var html = "";
            var pMenuBar = new MenuBar({});
            var pSubMenu = new DropDownMenu({});
            console.log('data : ' + data.toString());
            arrayUtil.forEach(data.items, function(item, i) {
                console.log(item[0].value);
                //console.log('item :' + item.name + '\r\n');
                //console.log('value : ' + item.value + '\r\n');
                    });
                        //html += "<dt>" + item.name +
                //    "</dt><dd>" + item.value +
                //    " (" + (typeof item.value) + ")</dd>";
            //});

                    //resultDiv.innerHTML = html;
            //pMenuBar.placeAt("wrapper");
            //pMenuBar.startup();
        },
            function(error) {
                // Display the error returned
                resultDiv.innerHTML = error;
            });
    });
</script>
```

What I need is a an example in how to iterate json data to populate dijit menubar.

```
<body class="claro">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'sidebar', gutters:true, liveSplitters:true" id="borderContainer">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="splitter:true, region:'leading'" style="width: 300px;">
        <div id="markup" style="width: 300px; height: 300px"></div>
        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="splitter:true, region:'center'">
        <div id="wrapper"></div>
        <div id="resultDiv"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I could really use some help on this one. Thanks for all the advice I can get.
Thank you! :)

Kind regards,
Jon Haakon

Answer (score 0):

I think I would make a recursive function that burrows down into the JSON structure you receive from the server, and builds menu items along the way.

Annoyingly, there is a small difference between items in the menu bar itself, and items in submenus belonging to the menu bar. The menu bar wants `dijit/PopupMenuBarItem` and `dijit/MenuBarItem` objects, while the popup menus themselves want `dijit/PopupMenuItem` and `dijit/MenuItem`, correspondingly.

Here's an example:

```js
function recursiveMakeMenuItem(data, id, inMenuBar) {

    // Get the item itself and its children (if any)
    var item = arrayUtil.filter(data, function(i){return i.MenuItemId==id;})[0],
        subs = arrayUtil.filter(data, function(i){return i.ParentId==id;}),
        widget = null, menu = null;

    if(subs.length) {
        // This item has children, so we need to make both an item that
        // triggers the a submenu (differentiating between items in the
        // menu bar and items in menus) and the submenu itself.
        widget = inMenuBar ? new PopupMenuBarItem() : new PopupMenuItem();
        menu   = new Menu();
        widget.set("popup", menu);
        // We then recursively dig deeper to generate the sub menus.
        arrayUtil.forEach(subs, function(item) {
            menu.addChild(recursiveMakeMenuItem(data, item.MenuItemId));
        });
    }
    else {
        // No children, but again we need to differentiate between items
        // in the menu bar and items in menus.
        widget = inMenuBar ? new MenuBarItem() : new MenuItem();       
    }
    widget.set("label", item ? item.MenuName : "ERROR id "+id);
    return widget;
}
```

In your code, you would call this when you receive data from the server. For example, if you wanted the single item with ParentId 0 to be the top level menu bar item, you could do:

```
request.post("/echo/json/", {
        handleAs: "json"
}).then(function(data) {
    var pMenuBar = new MenuBar({region: "top"});
    pMenuBar.addChild( recursiveMakeMenuItem(data.items, 1, true) );

    dijitRegistry.byId("borderContainer").addChild(pMenuBar);
    pMenuBar.startup();
});
```

Or, if everything with ParentId 1 should be top level items:

```
request.post("/echo/json/", {
        handleAs: "json"
}).then(function(data) {
    var pMenuBar = new MenuBar({region: "top"});
    arrayUtil.forEach(data.items, function(i) {
        if(i.ParentId !== 1) return;
        pMenuBar.addChild(recursiveMakeMenuItem(data.items, i.MenuItemId, true));
    });

    dijitRegistry.byId("borderContainer").addChild(pMenuBar);
    pMenuBar.startup();
});
```

Here's an example fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/2Gpkd/1/